# Excel Workbook to MongoDB. Ignoring null values

Tags: java, excel, mongodb

I am trying to import an excel worksheet to mongodb using java. But how to remove the entire collection which have null values?

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0d5e7a613ec898cbb64cd4"), 
    "ROLLNUMBER" : "222.0", 
    "NAME" : "PRASITA", 
    "TITLE" : "MODAL", 
    "AGE" : "23.0", 
    "ADDRESS" : "KOLKATA", 
    "ADDRESS_PIN" : "754215.0", 
    "PHNUMBER" : ""
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0d5e7a613ec898cbb64cd5"), 
    "ROLLNUMBER" : "333.0", 
    "NAME" : "MADHU", 
    "TITLE" : "DEY", 
    "AGE" : "24.0", 
    "ADDRESS" : "MUMBAI", 
    "ADDRESS_PIN" : "752463.0", 
    "PHNUMBER" : "8965248659,8965327454,6534674521"
}
```

How to remove this `"PHNUMBER"` attribute. (This is an empty cell in my excel sheeet)

Comment: This should be filtered during the import process, so the Java code should ignore empty values and not translate it to an empty string.

Comment: I did that but its not working. I have posted my code below. plz check once.thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may need to activate the blank non-activated cells. This is sometimes necessary when importing an Excel file into a system.

1. Select all the data in Excel
2. Press **Ctrl + F**
3. Leave **Find what:** empty
4. Click **Options >>**
5. Check **match entire cell contents**
6. Click **Find All**
7. Press **Ctrl + A** to select all the empty cells found
8. Close the Find dialog box
9. Press **Delete**
10. The cells will now be activated